# How to get URL from specific <img src=> and put into <a href=> for use with Lightbox

Tags: php, html, lightbox

I have built a site for someone else who will be updating it via a CMS (CushyCMS). They wanted a lightbox gallery included. I want to be able to allow them to upload a new image and for that image url to be copied into the a tag so lightbox works.

So far I am able to do that, but the client has to ensure the file names and format are exactly the same as what I have set them to in the php code. Is there a way to get the img url from the img tag (possibly identifying it using an id attribute) and put it directly into the  tag?

Heres what I have so far:

```
 <?php
 $src1 = "images/test1.jpg"; 
 $src2 = "images/test2.jpg"; 
 ?>  

<a href="<?php echo $src1?>" data-lightbox="group-1">
<img class="cushycms profile" name="image1" id="slideshow_image" src="images/test1.jpg"/></a>

<a href="<?php echo $src2?>" data-lightbox="group-1">  
<img class="cushycms profile" id="slideshow_image" src="images/test2.jpg"/></a>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Why is there no difference between what you put in the PHP and what is in the image tag?

Comment: because I want to use that image and echo it as a link in the <a> tag

Comment: Where did you get the image src from then? It is the same as your $src1 and $src2 - please post actual code so we can help you better. Your code snippet does not make sense as it is now

Comment: that is the image from my images file called test1.jpg. This is the actual code on the page and it works. Lightbox needs the a href to be the same as the image src. I need to automatically put the image src from the image tag as the href in the a tag.

Comment: I do not get this. If the code you have posted is what you have live, then 1) why do you have php, or 2) why is there no echo in the src of the image. You really need to detail what the user does, what you do and what you wish to do

Comment: i need to echo the img src in the a href! I want some code to do this automatically without me having to specify the file name for the $src to work.

Comment: this is for a website that someone else is editing. They are adding a new image and I want there new images to automatically be updated in the a href tag so it shows in the lightbox slideshow

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery:

```
<a data-lightbox="group-1">
    <img name="image1" src="images/test1.jpg" />
</a>

<script>
var img = $('img[name="image1"]');
var imgSrc = img.attr('src');

img.parent().attr('href', imgSrc);
</script>
```

---

If you have multiple images and want to automate this you can use the map function:

```
<a data-lightbox="group-1">
    <img name="image1" src="images/test1.jpg" class="slideshow" />
</a>

<a data-lightbox="group-1">
    <img name="image2" src="images/test2.jpg" class="slideshow" />
</a>

<a data-lightbox="group-1">
    <img name="image3" src="images/test3.jpg" class="slideshow" />
</a>

<script>
$(".slideshow").map(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('href', this.src);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank-you Matt! However I'm having some issue administering this, please could you correct me:      <script>
 var imgSrc = $('img[name="image1"]').attr('src');
$('a#imgsrc1').attr('href', imgSrc);
</script>
       <a id="imgsrc1" data-lightbox="group-1"><img class="cushycms profile" name="image1" id="slideshow_image" src="images/test1.jpg"/></a>

Comment: What's the issue you're having? Do you have jQuery on your site?

Comment: Your code would only work if the light box code is initialised after your change. Also please use parent instead of an ID

Comment: I have saved the file and have linked it like so: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>, is this correct?

Comment: @mplungjan Lightbox does not have any affect on the issue at hand. It is simply an image overlay script. It executes on the click of the link, not automatically upon page load. You are correct however that this can be made simpler by using the parent() selector. I will update the code sample above.

Comment: @user3507606 yes that's correct, are you still having issues?

Comment: @user3507606 I think I see what's wrong with your updated code. You must put the JavaScript **after** the HTML. The page is interpreted from top to bottom, so putting the JavaScript before the HTML means it will try to access the img tag before it's even created yet and will throw an error. See my updated example above.

Comment: Thankyou @MattK this works! Please could you demonstrate how this code will work to add subsequent image files to the a href tag? I can only get them to display the first image.

Comment: Must I repeat the script with different names: '<script>
var img = $('img[name="image1"]');

var imgSrc = img.attr('src');

img.parent().attr('href', imgSrc);

var img = $('img[name="image2"]');

var imgSrc = img.attr('src');

img.parent().attr('href', imgSrc);

var img = $('img[name="image3"]');

var imgSrc = img.attr('src');

img.parent().attr('href', imgSrc);
</script>'. This works, but could it be simpler?

Comment: @EmmaKate you can map it using jQuery, see my updated code above.

Comment: This is perfect thanks so much for your help @MattK really appreciate it!!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you use jQuery somewhere there, you could/should use a lightbox plugin, like this one here:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Using the xamples there, you would then use:
(http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

```
$('a.gallery').colorbox({rel:'group-1'});
```

which would result in a lighbox gallery showing on "click" on any anchor with class "gallery" while the gallery would show all the elements pointed by "href" from all anchors of that have class="group-1" (so each anchor would be

although you have to include some files for jquery and the lightbox plugin, I think it will make your life much easier in the end.

Also not sure what your php level is, but the example code you have there asks for:

```
<?php 

$images = array(
'images/test1.jpg',
'images/test2.jpg'
);

?>

<?php foreach($images as $i => $url): ?>

<a href="<?php echo $url?>" data-lightbox="group-1">
<img class="cushycms profile" name="image<?php echo $i+1 ?>" id="slideshow_image" src="<?php echo $url ?>"/>
</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Just in case you got more images there.